# Android: Instrumented test for location updates receives no location updates

Tags: android, kotlin, location, integration-testing

After I updated my phone to Android 12, my app (TargetSDKVersion 29) stopped to get location updates. So I have to update the app to API 31.

For this I want to write some instrumented tests for the location updates. I started with the simple test for `requestLocationUpdates()`. But in this simple test I don't get any location update.

Just in case I also adjusted the timestamps to 5s intervals to simulate some time between the updates - but no luck.

```
package de.leo.android.buddytracker_lib

import android.content.Context
import android.location.*
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test


private const val MOCK_PROVIDER = "MockLocationProvider"
private const val LOG_TAG ="****  Test  ****"

class LocationHandlerAndroidTests : LocationListener {
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var locationManager: LocationManager

    private var locationUpdateCount = 0
    private var currentLocation: Location? = null


    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        locationUpdateCount++
        currentLocation = location
    }


    @Before
    fun init() {
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        locationManager.addTestProvider(
            MOCK_PROVIDER,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            Criteria.POWER_LOW,
            Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
        )
        locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(MOCK_PROVIDER, true)

        assertTrue(locationManager.isLocationEnabled)

        locationUpdateCount = 0
        currentLocation = null

        Thread.sleep(5000L)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        locationManager.removeTestProvider(MOCK_PROVIDER)
    }

    @Test
    fun requestLocationUpdatesTest() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Requesting Location Updates")
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(MOCK_PROVIDER, 4000, 10.0f, this, Looper.getMainLooper())

        val location1 = Location(MOCK_PROVIDER)
        location1.latitude = 10.0
        location1.longitude = 20.0
        location1.accuracy = 2.0f
        location1.time = 1000
        location1.elapsedRealtimeNanos = 10000000000

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "set location 1")
        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(MOCK_PROVIDER, location1)

        Thread.sleep(5000L)

        val location2 = Location(MOCK_PROVIDER)
        location2.latitude = 11.0
        location2.longitude = 21.0
        location2.accuracy = 2.0f
        location2.time = 5000
        location2.elapsedRealtimeNanos = 15000000000

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "set location 2")
        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(MOCK_PROVIDER, location2)

        Thread.sleep(5000L)

        // Check if your listener reacted the right way
        assertEquals("Got location updates", 2, locationUpdateCount)
        assertEquals(11.0, currentLocation?.latitude)
        assertEquals(21.0, currentLocation?.longitude)
    }
}
```

Any tips what I made wrong here?